# How do I diagnose battery drain whilst asleep?

Tags: battery

Today I've had my 2017 MacBook Pro asleep in my bag all day.  I left home with it at 100% battery and ended up not using it for the entire day, I didn't even open the lid.  When I got home, I opened it and it was at 0%.  Here is the chart from the "Energy" tab of the Activity Monitor, you can see the green areas where it was on charge.

[image: Battery panel in activity monitor]

How do I diagnose what caused the battery to be entirely depleted? Other than this small chart I can't find any historical data about "Energy Impact".

Answer (score 1):

I have not found anything that satifactorily answers my original question of how to see historical battery usage (Apple calls it "Energy Impact" in Activity Monitor).

But to diagnose what might be happening over the time period I followed the process here: [2016 Touch Bar MBP drains battery in sleep](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/293641/2016-touch-bar-mbp-drains-battery-in-sleep?rq=1) of looking at system logs.

There were a lot of repeated errors from GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent throughout the day.  I don't know if this is the cause of battery drain, but in case it is, I followed these instructions to remove it: https://superuser.com/questions/730736/how-to-remove-google-software-update-from-mac-osx

On High Sierra, it was:

`$ ~/Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate/GoogleSoftwareUpdate.bundle/Contents/Resources/GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent.app/Contents/Resources/ksinstall --nuke
$ defaults write com.google.Keystone.Agent checkInterval 0`

Answer (score 0):

From this other question ( [Macbook Air - battery drains while sleeping (but not when shut down)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/156871/macbook-air-battery-drains-while-sleeping-but-not-when-shut-down) ), I found the useful command with an output limited to wakes:

```
pmset -g log|grep -e " Sleep  " -e " Wake  "
```

A command for more complete outputs would be (from [What does my Mac do while sleeping all night long?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/423593/what-does-my-mac-do-while-sleeping-all-night-long/) ):

```
pmset -g log | egrep "\b(Sleep|Wake|DarkWake|Start)\s{2,}"
```

At least from here you can find clues about what woke up your Mac, and investigate!